# Highlighting Text With Keyboard Between Limits On Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text I can highlight text between specific locations by holding down shift and clicking the start of the region I want highlighted and then the end.

How do I do this with just the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the key command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> on Windows when you are at the beginning or in the middle somewhere of a document. This works with any program.

Comment: Thanks but this does not select the text between two specified locations, it selects it between one specified location and the end of the file.

Comment: Oh you want two locations. Can you do "Shift + Down Arrow" until you get to where you want? I do not think it is possible to do two locations.

Comment: Thanks very much, shift + arrows does exactly what I want, can't believe I missed that...

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

Explore the commands in the `Edit` > `Mark` submenu.

Move your cursor to the start of the desired selection and run `Set Mark` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>).

Then move your cursor to the end of the desired selection and run `Select to Mark` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

## Method 2

Or, as noted in the comments, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you move across the desired selection (using arrows, etc.).